# How to turn bug's head according to its general direction?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create quite simple animation of a bug crawling over the site's certain places. Random movement looks liek this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    bug();

});

function makeNewPosition(){

    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh,nw];    

}

function bug(){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    $('.bug').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, 2000, function(){
      bug();        
    });

};
```

here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tgpvhLx7/

What I am looking for is: **how to turn the bug during the animation** so it actually "looks" in front of "him" while walking?

**UPDATE**

Here is how we can deduct the angle:

```
OldY = 100;
NewY = 50;

OldX = 100;
NewX = 50;

y = OldY - NewY;
x = OldX - NewX;
angle = Math.atan2(y, x);
angle *= 180/Math.PI
angle = Math.ceil(angle);
```

Comment: LOgically - I have to deduct an angle degree (45....86....120) based on the initial (starting) point and a destination point.  So (as an example) if teh starting poing is: left: 100; top: 100; and destination point is: left: 50; top: 50;  - that would mean 45 degrees (or rather 135 degrees) and that's good enough info to turn the div with either CSS rotation or with jquery rotate. 
Thinking.... =)

Comment: Looks like I am nearly there (see the update!!!)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It is done! Thanks all =)
Here is how I have solved this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    bug();

});

function makeNewPosition() {

    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh, nw];

}

function bug() {
    var newq = makeNewPosition();

    var p = $('.bug').offset();

    OldY = p.top;
    NewY = newq[0];

    OldX = p.left;
    NewX = newq[1];

    y = OldY - NewY;
    x = OldX - NewX;
    angle = Math.atan2(y, x);
    angle *= 180 / Math.PI
    angle = Math.ceil(angle);

    $(".bug").rotate(angle);



    $('.bug').animate({
        top: newq[0],
        left: newq[1]
    }, 2000, function () {
        bug();
    });

};
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xw29r/3850/

JqueryRotate is used to rotate div after the initial and final coordinates are found and the angle is deducted:

http://jqueryrotate.com/#examples